# how to query mongo profile greater than a specific date

Tags: mongodb

How do I query Mongodb profiler greater than a specific date

```
db.system.profile.find( { millis : { $gt:20000 } } ).sort( { ts : { $gt:ISODate("2020-07-29T02:10:01.132Z") and $lt:ISODate("2020-07-29T10:10:01.132Z") } } ).pretty()
```

Comment: please post some sample data

Comment: The data values must be in `find({})`, you put them in the `sort`

Answer (score 0):

Read this documentation
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/

```
db.system.profile.find({
  millis: {
    $gt: 20000
  },
  ts: {
    $gt: ISODate("2020-07-29T02:10:01.132Z")
  }
}).sort({
  ts: 1
}).pretty()
```